# Why am I obtaining this certificate error trying to perform this cURL request? SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target hostname

Tags: ssl, curl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am not so into certificate and I have the following issue that I am trying to debug.

A Java application try to connect to an external API over **HTTPS** proticol but in the application log I obtain the following error message:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2020-02-29 13:34:58,686] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}   
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

So I asked the guys that handle the machine on which this external API is hosted to provide me the certificate. They send me a **self signed certificate**.

So first I tried to perform the API call by **cURL** from the same machine where my application is deployed.

First thing I tried to perform the API call using the **-k** option on the **cURL** request:

```
curl -k -X POST "https://MY_HOST_NAME/cmd/j/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"header\": { \"msgUid\": \"a36bea3f-6dc6-49d7-9376-f31692930ba9\",..........................}}"
```

As I can read on the **cURL** documentation: 
https://gist.github.com/eneko/dc2d8edd9a4b25c5b0725dd123f98b10

the **-k** or **--insecure** allow connections to SSL sites without certs. It works fine. The API return the expected response.

ThenI try to use the provided certificate, so now I performed the **cURL** request including this certificate, in this way:

```
curl --cacert /home/my_username/ca.crt -X POST "https://MY_HOST_NAME/cmd/j/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"header\": { \"msgUid\": \"a36bea3f-6dc6-49d7-9376-f31692930ba9\",..........................}}"
```

As you can see I included the provided certificate using the **--cacert** option. The problem is that now I am obtaining the following error:

```
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target hostname MY_HOST_NAME
```

What it means? Could this certificate be wrong? I suspect that the problem is the provided certificate for 2 reasons:

1) Opening the certificate into Windows I obtain something like this:

[image]

I was noticing that the **CN** field value **(that should represents the server name protected by the SSL certificate**) is different from the hostname called in my API (The one that I obscured as **MY_HOST_NAME** in the previous request). It seems that the certificate is related to another hostname.

My problem could be related to this?

2) The guy that send me the certificate wrote me something like this:

> This is the certificate (and he attached it to the mail), I suggest
>   you to set the igore settings related to the certificate error using
>   it into the DMZ (and the caller machine should be into this DMZ)
>   because it is self signed and so the alternative name inside the
>   certificate should also be changed.

So I suspect that this certificate is not good because point to another server name.

Is it my reasoning correct? I am absolutly not into SSL certificate and I am asking: there is a way to change this name by myself or they have to provide me a new certificate with the correct name?